# Parse.com Array to NSMutableArray in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swifty-json

I have stored an with a few words in a column in Parse class. I want retrieve all the contents of the array and would like to save it on NSMutableArray, so that I can do further manipulation. I have used SwiftyJSON without success. I am not able to get any value for "**var json**"

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class Words: NSObject {

    var englishSubjectWordArray: NSArray = NSArray()
    var chineseSubjectWordArray: NSArray = NSArray()



    func querysubject() {
        let query = PFQuery(className:"SubjectWords")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("HBMWq9yWin"){
            (objects: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && objects != nil {
               // print(objects)

                let json: JSON =  JSON(rawValue: objects!)!
                print(json)
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm confused — why are you attempting to make JSON from a `PFObject`?

Answer (score 0):

objects is already an array of PFObjects, you don't need to convert the JSON. You can manipulate the data from the PFObjects. just create an NSMutableArray and set it to objects.

Comment: englishSubjectWordArray = (objects.englishSubjectWords) as NSMutableArray , However, I am getting an error saying : Type of expression is ambigous without more context.